# Reading argument via vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Looking for a little advice with the following - i'm passing an onclick event with an argument into JS as follows:

```
<div class="artistthumb" id="jamesPaterson1" onclick="artistModalOpen('jamesPaterson1')"></div>
```

This enters the following JS function:

```
function artistModalOpen(x1) {
    var imagePath = document.getElementById(x1).style.backgroundImage;
    console.log(x1);
    console.log(imagePath);
}
```

The CSS for the id is:

```
background-image: url(../img/james_paterson_1.jpg);
```

So far i'm just logging the 2 console outputs - the first is fine, console displays argument x1 as expected: `jamesPaterson1`

The second console log doesn't show anything.

I would have expected to see `url(../img/james_paterson_1.jpg)`

Anyone know why this isn't happening?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The `style` object does not show CSS rules that come from stylesheets,

Comment: @Pointy that'll be it! Thank you!

Comment: You can use getComputedStyle that will achieve your purpose https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getComputedStyle`

```
var imagePath = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(x1))
                .getPropertyValue('background-image');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

> The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports
>   the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active
>   stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
>   contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs
>   provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.